# How to fix java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/common/R$string in android studio 3.6.1?

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio-3.6.1

I have updated android studio 3.6.1 and com.google.gms:google-services to 4.3.3 and all firebase libraries too updated to latest version. My problem is app is crashing when launching and showing the below logs. How to solve it? Help is much appreciated . Thanks in advance

```html
2020-03-17 15:49:00.676 16943-16943/? E/Zygote: isWhitelistProcess - Process is Whitelisted
2020-03-17 15:49:00.677 16943-16943/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 1
2020-03-17 15:49:00.682 16943-16943/? I/com.mypackage.app: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
2020-03-17 15:49:00.739 16943-16973/? E/com.mypackage.app: Failed to send DDMS packet REAQ to debugger (-1 of 20): Broken pipe
2020-03-17 15:49:00.926 16943-16943/? I/com.mypackage.app: The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
2020-03-17 15:49:02.102 16943-16943/com.mypackage.app I/MultiDex: VM with version 2.1.0 has multidex support
2020-03-17 15:49:02.102 16943-16943/com.mypackage.app I/MultiDex: Installing application
2020-03-17 15:49:02.102 16943-16943/com.mypackage.app I/MultiDex: VM has multidex support, MultiDex support library is disabled.
2020-03-17 15:49:02.110 16943-16943/com.mypackage.app D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2020-03-17 15:49:02.113 16943-16943/com.mypackage.app E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.mypackage.app, PID: 16943
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/common/R$string;
        at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.StringResourceValueReader.<init>(Unknown Source:4)
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions.fromResource(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@19.3.0:156)
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@19.3.0:244)
        at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@19.3.0:51)
        at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1940)
        at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1915)
        at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@19.3.0:45)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6742)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:6289)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6204)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:237)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1785)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7050)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:965)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.common.R$string" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.boot.jar", zip file "/data/app/com.kintapp.kint-p3Tr4wqxqUEo0V_RqsvUvA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.kintapp.kint-p3Tr4wqxqUEo0V_RqsvUvA==/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.kintapp.kint-p3Tr4wqxqUEo0V_RqsvUvA==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system/vendor/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.StringResourceValueReader.<init>(Unknown Source:4) 
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions.fromResource(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@19.3.0:156) 
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@19.3.0:244) 
        at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@19.3.0:51) 
        at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1940) 
        at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1915) 
        at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@19.3.0:45) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6742) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:6289) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6204) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:237) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1785) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7050) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:965) 
2020-03-17 15:49:02.140 16943-16943/com.kintapp.kint I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 16943 SIG: 9
```

[image]

Comment: Did you try clear cache and rebuild ?

Comment: Yes, did two time

Comment: also, add this line inside build.gradle

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

Comment: That was added when i start this project

Comment: can you send build gradle snippet ?

Comment: i have added now

Comment: try after enabling multidex

Comment: i am using  implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1' already

Answer (score 4):

If you are a realm user, you may upgrade the version of the plugin to the latest stable version.
If not, can you provide your gradle files please ?

Comment: We can't help you if you don't paste your whole grade files

Answer (score 1):

as a temp solution in my case i did Clean Project from `Build`, then `Clean Project` then `Build` then `Rebuild project` .